# Super key (Win key) not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, windows

I have this strange behavior where when I press super(win) key in my laptop a block symbol is showing, but when using external keyboard for super(win) key it works fine. The win key is not also working in windows too.

[image: win key error screenshot]

Comment: you have not specified OS version so guessing from tag that it is 20.04 but when you say it's not working in win also, it seems something is broken from hw side. Nonetheless, for ubuntu, can post details from settings->Region & Language-> Input Sources, what layout you see. There is also a eye button when you click it it shows layout of the user. You can paste that image here for reference.

Comment: @KunalShah the problem is with my Acer Laptop, I have Acer nitro 5 which has nitro sense application, where the win key is disabled. I have enabled in that nitro sense application.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue is with laptop. I have windows as well as ubuntu (dual boot) where the `nitro sense` application has switch option to disable the win key (super key) functionality that leads to problem in ubuntu.

If it's not the solution make sure to check the answer in [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-key-not-working-already-tried-all-thing-on/0c796f79-0aa8-466e-ab44-802005d1791b) page for more solution.